# Blank page after create new object for MongoDB in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I create a `MongoDBConnect.php` file as below:

```
<?php
require_once('./vendor/autoload.php');
class MongoDBConnect{
    function __construct()
    {

        $this->db = (new MongoDB\Client)->db_visualization->col_visualization;
    }
    public function fetchLongLat()
    {
        return $this->db->find();
    }

}?>
```

and then I call it `index.php` using require once as below:

```
<?php
require_once('./MongoDBConnect.php');
$db = new MongoDBConnect;?>
```

When I remove `$db = new MongoDBConnect;`, the page works fine, but when it is in there, the page is blank.

I am currently running `PHP 7.0.xx` and `Apache 2.xx` on `LAMP` for `Ubuntu`. I'm pretty new to this so hoping that someone could help me out. I can offer a coffee if you are in Melbourne. Thank you!

Comment: turn on error reporting...

Answer (score -1):

Probably you need to install the `MongoDB` extension on your PHP installation.

Run this command:

```
sudo pecl install mongodb
```

After, put this extension in your `php.ini` configuration.

Comment: I have already done this. If I use the command in the php -s 127.0.0.1:2020 then it worked fine. But when I copy it to the html folder it didnt work ..